# What does means * in array allocation before size declaration in C++?

Tags: c++

```
table = new myObject*[TABLE_SIZE];
```

I know that * are for declaring pointers variable and to obtain the value of the variable from a pointer, but what does this mean?

Comment: Note that this is typically bad C++ style. A better solution would be `std::vector<myObject*> table(TABLE_SIZE, nullptr)`. But I suspect there are more problems, such as the use of non-smart pointers and possible a ` #define TABLE_SIZE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly what you already know it means :-)

The type `myObject *` is a *pointer* to a `myObject` object so what you are declaring is an array of said pointers, `TABLE_SIZE` of them to be exact.

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly that.

`table` is a pointer to an array (with size `TABLE_SIZE`) of *pointers* to objects of type `myObject`. Note that you haven't *allocated* any memory for those pointers at this point.

Don't forget to call `delete[] table;` once you're done with it.

Comment: ... or better, just replace with `std::vector<myObject> table(TABLE_SIZE);` and stop having to worry about calling `delete []`.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you allocate an array of type `myObject*` of size `TABLE_SIZE`.

So in this case we allocate space for the pointers but not the objects.

Your variable `table` will then be a pointer to an array of pointers, or a `myObject**`.

So `table` will point to the first element in this list of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk means pointer here too. I am *assuming* that `table` is declared like

```
myObject** table;
```

What you are doing is allocating an "array" of `TABLE_SIZE` *pointers* to `myObject`.